Why Saxon was worse than East German?
From John Le Carré's Smiley's People:

“Otto Leipzig never settled anywhere in his life,” said Toby with contempt. “George, that guy’s a drifter, a total bum. Dresses like he was a Rothschild, owns a cat and a bicycle. Know what his last job was, this great spy? Night-watchman in some lousy Hamburg cargo house somewhere! Forget him.”
“And he had a partner,” Smiley said, in the same tone of innocent reminiscence. “Yes, that comes back to me too. An immigrant, an East German.”
“Worse than East German: Saxon. Name of Kretzschmar, first name was Claus. Claus with a ‘C,’ don’t ask me why. I mean these guys have got no logic at all. Claus was also a creep. They stole together, pimped together, faked reports together.”

Why Toby thought Saxon was worse than East German? Was it just the prejudice of Toby (or rather, Le Carré himself), or was it a common belief?

Don't assume that because an author writes a character with prejudices that means the author has those prejudices.

I don't think there is a reason why Toby thinks Saxons are worse than East Germans in general (Saxony is part of East Germany). Toby has a number of prejudices and doesn't in general think well of people, as demonstrated by the rest of the passage.

@DJClayworth Toby explained why he detested Otto Leipzig and Kretzschmar, which might not make sense but was at least logical. However, he didn't provide any logical reason about why he thought Saxon was worse. Anyway, it seems it's not a common belief and that's all I want to confirm actually. Thanks for your comment.

Toby might be making a light-hearted, illogical remark which he doesn't expect Smiley to take seriously.  There is certainly humour in his first statement.

Saxons have a reputation among Germans for being a bit slow, and there are lots of jokes about them.

@ClaraDiazSanchez thanks for your comment. Good to know.

There are few dialects more despised in Germany than the Saxon dialect.
Here is a ranking of German dialects as perceived by Germans (in German):
https://www.welt.de/kmpkt/article246898938/Dialekte-Umfrage-zeigt-das-sind-die-unbeliebtesten-Dialekte-Deutschlands.html
An automated English translation of the salient points follows:

But which regional variant of German comes off worst overall? This was the question posed by a new survey. An independent opinion research institute surveyed more than 1,000 women and men aged between 16 and 65 from Germany on behalf of the online language learning platform "Preply". They were asked to state which of 18 selected German dialects they liked the least. Multiple answers were allowed.



Saxon (37.6 percent)
Swabian (19.3 percent)
Bavarian (18.6 percent)
Thuringian (17 percent)
Schwyzerdütsch (15.9 percent)



Hi and welcome to LiteSE. Is there any evidence in the novel that Toby detests Kretzschmar specifically for his Saxon dialect? If so, please provide that evidence, otherwise it's not clear how this answers the question. Also, there's a difference between noting a prejudice and indulging that prejudice. Your statement "Believe me, when you hear it you will know why" is goes against Stack Exchange's be nice policy. Please edit this answer to address these problems and prevent its deletion. Thanks!

@verbose I suppose it's not necessary to find solid evidence about that. Regina suggests a possibility and provides a link with more information, which is helpful. As I said, I just want to confirm that if it's a common belief that people don't like Saxon. And Regina suggests a possibility which makes some sense.  That's good enough to me.

@verbose It seems easy enough to edit this to "be nice" and still keep the thrust of the answer - I will do so if the answerer neglects to.

In this segment of text, Toby is being gently interrogated by Smiley as to why he didn't respond to Vladimir's proposition. Toby is clearly feeling defensive - he did not feel that the intelligence was worth acting on because he thought that the source was worthless - and so he emphasises as much as possible how unreliable Otto Leipzig and his partner were:

“And he had a partner,” Smiley said, in the same tone of innocent
reminiscence. “Yes, that comes back to me too. An immigrant, an East
German.”
“Worse than East German: Saxon.

Since Saxony was a region of East Germany, this may read rather oddly.
Although he had his peculiarities, Toby Esterhase was always portrayed as being competent. Earlier in the scene he reminisces about the exact location of the East German border:

Know where the East German border is up there? From Lübeck two
kilometres? Less? Remember? In Travemünde you got to stay on the left
of the street or you've defected by mistake.'

and so it seems unlikely that someone so knowledgeable about the region would mistake the location of Saxony. I would rather interpret this as a form of exaggeration - not only was Kretzschmar East German, but he was the worst kind of East German, a Saxon. Saxons, rightly or wrongly have a reputation for being boring and stupid. There are many jokes are based on this stereotype1, and this view of them was probably reinforced by their very distinctive regional dialect, which as another answer points out, is regarded as unpleasant. Indeed even today, comedians will assume a Saxon dialect to make themselves sound stupid/uncultured.
[1] Many countries have regions which are the butt of jokes. Spaniards make jokes about the supposed stupidity of people from Lepe, the English make jokes about the Welsh, and so on.

The Welsh? I thought the Irish are the commonest butt of English jokes. (And the people of Kerry, for Irish jokes.)

@Randal'Thor add further examples as you wish  ;)

I don’t think we are meant to take Toby’s claim seriously here; indeed, the claim is self-contradictory, since Saxony was part of East Germany. Rather, it is a sign that Toby is grasping at straws in an attempt to put off Smiley from pursuing his investigation into the assassination of General Vladimir. Here’s how Toby introduces the name of Otto Leipzig into the conversation:

‘And you want to hear why, maybe? You want to know why I told him, “Go to hell, Vladimir. Leave my sight, please, you make me sick.”? You want to know who his connect is out there—this magic guy in North Germany with the crock of gold that’s going to make millionaires of us overnight, George—you want to know his full identity? Remember the name Otto Leipzig, by any chance? Holder many times of our Creep of the Year award? Fabricator, intelligence pedlar, confidence man, sex maniac, pimp, also various sorts of criminal? Remember that great hero?’
John Le Carré (1979). Smiley’s People, chapter 13. London: Hodder and Stoughton.

It’s not completely clear to me why Toby is so insistent that Smiley should give up the chase. Perhaps it is because he knows that he behaved badly when he refused to help Vladimir and so feels guilty over the general’s death. Or perhaps he fears that Smiley would meet a similar end, and this is how he shows concern for his former colleague. Or maybe it is a habitual secretiveness acquired after decades of spying for a living.
Whatever the reason, Toby attempts to dissuade Smiley using hyperbolic rhetoric (for example, it is doubtful that the Circus actually had a “Creep of the Year” award), and this leads him to make the claim about the ethnicity of Claus Kretzschmar, along with the other slanders quoted in the question.

the Circus may not officially have a “Creep of the Year” award, but its agents may discuss about that topic in their private talk, maybe as sort of a game. Toby for sure exaggerates to some extent, for the reason you clearly explained, but he probably has some reason in claiming Saxon is worse. He's not likely to make this claim out of nothing.

I don't interpret the claim as being contradictory, as much as "non solum, sed etiam". Like someone asking "Is he British?" and getting the reply "Worse than that, he's Welsh" (Apologies to British and Welsh readers)
